# Fixed height of Vega-lite table rows

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to put together a table-like layout of data visualization using the code below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "height": 60,
  "width": 500,
  "autosize": {
    "type": "fit",
    "resize": true
  },
  "data": {
     "values": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "1",
          "jobStreamName": "Stream 1",
          "executionStatus": "SUCC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "2",
          "jobStreamName": "Stream 2",
          "executionStatus": "HOLD"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "3",
          "jobStreamName": "Stream 3",
          "executionStatus": "ABEND"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "4",
          "jobStreamName": "Stream 4",
          "executionStatus": "SUCC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "document_id": "5",
          "jobStreamName": "Stream 5",
          "executionStatus": "SUCC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    // document_id header
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 0},
        "y": {"value": -20},
        "text": {"value": "Document ID"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    // document_id values
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 0},
        "y": {"field": "_source.document_id", "type": "ordinal"},
        "text": {"field": "_source.document_id", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    // jobStreamName header
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 180},
        "y": {"value": -20},
        "text": {"value": "Job Stream Name"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    // jobStreamName values
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 180},
        "y": {"field": "_source.document_id", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null},
        "text": {"field": "_source.jobStreamName", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    // executionStatus header
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 340},
        "y": {"value": -20},
        "text": {"value": "Execution Status"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    },
    // executionStatus values
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 340},
        "y": {"field": "_source.document_id", "type": "ordinal"},
        "text": {"field": "_source.executionStatus", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {
          "condition": [
            {"test": "datum._source.executionStatus === 'SUCC'", "value": "green"},
            {"test": "datum._source.executionStatus === 'HOLD'", "value": "yellow"},
            {"test": "datum._source.executionStatus === 'ABEND'", "value": "red"}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "axis": {"grid": false, "ticks": false, "labels": false, "title": null},
    "view": {"stroke": null}
  }
}
```

Not sure this is the optimal solution, since I run into trouble when rows are adding up at a certain point when the text begins to overlap.
[image]

Is it possible to prevent the squeezing or stretching of those spaces between rows based on their numbers? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove line 4 (`"height": 60,`) which specifies that the height of the view *must be* 60 pixels, which means that the rows are compressed to fit within that space. If this line is excluded from the visualization, the view size with expand/contract based on the number of rows, and the height of each row will remain fixed:

[image: table visualization with better row spacing]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in Vega editor. However in my Kibana visualization where I am using the Vega-lite specification, this don't have the desired effect.